# Bootstrap 3.3.1 - Highlight Current Navigation Menu Item

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu-items

The script that I use currently works well actually, as long as I keep my file structure like this:

```
http://website.com/
http://website.com/page1.php
http://website.com/page2.php
http://website.com/page3.php
```

but when I impliment my mod_rewrite code to take away the ".php"

```
http://website.com/
http://website.com/page1
http://website.com/page2
http://website.com/page3
```

my navigation highlight script stops working.

Here is how I implement my code

The HTML

```
<body id="page1">
```

The JS

```
$(function() {

    //highlight the current nav
    //each of the following lines represents a different page
    $("#page1 a:contains('Page 1')").parent().addClass('active');
    $("#page2 a:contains('Page 2')").parent().addClass('active');



});
```

The ID within the JS looks for the ID within each body tag, and the part that says ('Page 1') looks for the item within the menu to identify which menu item to highlight. As I said, it works fine, until take away the .php. I'm assuming it has something to do with .parent within the js, but I'm not sure what to replace it with, or how to make it work right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a  fiddle or a screenshot of your page to illustrate the issue?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, each of your pages have an unique `<body>` id? Like, if  `page2.php` is called, `<body id="page2">`  and that's the active page, right?

Comment: @RamisWachtler - yes you are correct

Comment: @NLN - I am not sure what fiddle is, except for the musical instrument, I'll have to google it! When you say a screen shot, do you mean of the code, or of the actual web page? Currently I don't have it available online, I am working on it on my workstation with MAMP.

Comment: @AileenEverlast he means [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @AileenEverlast: Can you somehow share the **structure of code** for your 'navigation menu' ? I mean, how are your <a> (anchor tags) wrapped ? Since .parent() is not working as you mentioned, thats probably because you are adding 'active' class at wrong place ?

Comment: @NLN I have figured out this fiddle thing, here is a link http://jsfiddle.net/aileeneverlast/su9LjL4w/

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vxq8qnpf/) is a link to your updated fiddle. Change the body ID and you can "switch" through navigation.

Comment: @RamisWachtler - I wanted to let you know that the last solution you just posted above [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/vxq8qnpf/) worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help, I do very much appreciate it! If you would like, you can update your answer that you posted here, and I will place a check mark next to it :-) Thank you soooooo much!

Comment: @AileenEverlast no problem! I'm glad I could help you! (Answer is updated) ;-)

Comment: @RamisWachtler - Hello once again! I was working with this JS that you helped me with, and I have run into a problem. It works great on pages 1 - 5, but when I use the id page6 it no longer functions on the 6th page - is there a way to make this work beyond page 5? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aileeneverlast/vxq8qnpf/8/) - Thank you once again for your patients and help!

Comment: @RamisWachtler - my goodness you are quick! Thank you once again :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `<body>` tag in each of your pages, contains an unique ID, you could just check if this id is existing.

Like this **(UPDATED)**:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $(".menu-item").length; i++){
    var item = i+1;
    if($("#page"+item).length>0){
        $("li:nth-child("+item+")").addClass("active");
        break;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** Your updated fiddle

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxq8qnpf/9/)

Comment: I apologies for my ignorance - am I suppose to replace this with the JS I already have - or am I suppose to somehow integrate it into the script? I tried replacing it with the script you provided, but I'm afraid it didn't work. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!

Comment: It should replace your code. Could you also post the content of your page1.php or at least your navigation?

Comment: I've also added a fiddle to my answer, check it out.

Comment: The ID in the `<body>` tag identifies the correct page, and the bit of code that says `a:contains('Page 1')` looks for the text within the `<li>` tag to identify which menu item to highlight. does that make sense?

Comment: It will add `.active` class to every matching element. Example:

`// will match because there is an element "Home" on page1
$("#page1 a:contains('Home')").parent().addClass('active');
// will ALSO match because there is also an element "Rates" on page1
$("#page1 a:contains('Rates')").parent().addClass('active');`